# mysql recibir procedimiento almacenado genérico

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedure, genericos

Estoy utilizando procedimientos almacenados desde **C#**, he estado intentando crear un método genérico al cual se le pasa el nombre del procedimiento almacenado, los parámetros de entrada y que devuelva el valor que este retorne, la verdad lo he intentado pero llego a un punto en donde no se como poder recorrer los parámetros de entrada, 
el método **intentoDeParametrosDeEntrada** se supone que devuelve el nombre del parámetro de entrada y el tipo de dato que es

```
public static List<ParamsGrupo> intentoDeParametrosDeEntrada()
{
        List<ParamsGrupo> lst_params = new List<ParamsGrupo>();

        ParamsGrupo pNombre = new ParamsGrupo();
        pNombre.nombreParametro = "NOMBRE";
        pNombre.tipoParametro = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        lst_params.Add(pNombre);
        return lst_params;
}
```

el método **metodoGenerico** se supone que es donde se le pasan los parámetros de entrada, el nombre del procedimiento almacenado.

```
public static string metodoGenerico(Grupo grupo)
{

       MySqlConnection con = Conexion.DAO.Conexion.obtenerConexion();
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("PA_AGREGAR_GRUPO", con);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?NOMBRE",grupo.nombre_grupo);
       cmd.Parameters["?NOMBRE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

       cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?ID", MySqlDbType.Int64));
       cmd.Parameters["?ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

       Int64 retval = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       Int64 id = (Int64)cmd.Parameters["?ID"].Value;
       con.Close();
       return id.ToString();

}
```

La verdad llegue a un punto en donde no se me ocurre como poder hacerlo, no pido que lo programen por mi, pero una ayudita no me vendría nada mal.

Saludos!.

Comment: Para que quieres saber los datos de entrada con intentoDeParametrosDeEntrada
Si con   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue no los necesitas

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Pues explicar mejor con que exactamente estás teniendo problemas?

Comment: ¿Estás intentando crear un método para con él poder mandar ejecutar cualquier procedimiento almacenado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo tengo este código para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados:

```
public System.Data.DataTable ExecuteSP(string procedimiento, params MySqlParameter[] datos)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = ...)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(datos);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Para ser ejecutado:

```
DataTable datos = claseDeConexion.ExecuteSP("P_TraeDatos",
                  new MySqlParameter("paramA", parametroA),
                  new MySqlParameter("paramB", parametroB),
                  new MySqlParameter("paramC", parametroC)...);
```

Ese método retornará una tabla de resultados. También se puede hacer con un `DataSet`:

```
connection.Open();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    connection.Close();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

O con un `object` (un solo valor):

```
object dbResult = DBNull.Value;
using (MySqlConnection connection = ...)
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(datos);
        connection.Open();
        dbResult = cmnd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
return dbResult;
```

---

### ¿Cómo ocuparlo?

Suponiendo que quieras obtener un `int` a partir del procedimiento almacenado, yo te recomendaría usar el último método que escribí arriba, pero para que quede más claro lo pondré completo:

```
public object ExecuteScalarSP(string procedimiento, params MySqlParameter[] datos)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = ...)
        {
            object dbResult = DBNull.Value;
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(datos);
                connection.Open();
                dbResult = cmnd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            return dbResult;
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Devuelve un `object` ya que no lo sabe interpretar directamente.

Para invocarlo como indicas en el comentario, sería así:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(objConsultas.ExecuteScalarSP("P_Procedimiento",
                               new MySqlParameter("paramA", variableA),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramB", variableB),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramC", variableC),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramD", variableD),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramE", variableE)));
```

Yo lo usaría en conjunto con un método para convertir `objects` en `int` (para cuando sea por consulta) y evitar que cree una excepción si es `null`:

```
public static int GetDbInt32(object DbResult)
{
    return DBNull.Value.Equals(DbResult) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(DbResult);
}
```

Y quedaría así:

```
int result = GetDbInt32(objConsultas.ExecuteScalarSP("P_Procedimiento",
                               new MySqlParameter("paramA", variableA),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramB", variableB),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramC", variableC),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramD", variableD),
                               new MySqlParameter("paramE", variableE)));
```

---

### Con parámetro de salida

Para definir la dirección del parámetro, puedes utilizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> ExecuteOutputSP(string procedimiento, params MySqlParameter[] datos)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = ...)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(procedimiento, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(datos);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (MySqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
                    if (p.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input) dictionary.Add(p.ParameterName, p.Value);

                return dictionary;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}

int result = GetDbInt32(objConsultas.ExecuteOutputSP("P_Procedimiento",
                 new MySqlParameter("paramA", variableA),
                 new MySqlParameter("paramB", variableB),
                 new MySqlParameter("paramC", variableC),
                 new MySqlParameter("paramD", variableD),
                 new MySqlParameter("paramE", variableE),
                 new MySqlParameter("paramF", variableF){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output })["paramF"]);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, me surge una duda y disculpa mi ignorancia pero si por ejemplo, mi procedimiento almacenado recibe 5 parametros y me devuelve un int, como seria para ocupar tu metodo?

Comment: @Hersenfels Ya actualicé mi respuesta, ¡espero que te ayude!

Comment: siempre me lanza el mismo error, mi procedimiento almacenado tiene 5 parámetros IN y 1 OUT, primero hace un insert y luego hace un select y retorno un ID, si escribo 5 parámetros IN y no mando el OUT me reclama de que debo enviar los 6 parámetros, si escribo los 6 parámetros , el parámetro OUT no se como escribirlo , ya que no envió datos sino que recibo, nose si seria "new MySqlParameter("paramE", variableE)));" de ese modo el OUT, cuando envio los 6 parametros me retorna nada.

Comment: @Hersenfels a ver, es que como te dije en un comentario tu pregunta no era clara. Para marcar un parámetro como output, debes indicarlo en la definición del parámetro añadiendo: `.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: Por cierto @KroneauxSchneider, tal vez debas editar tu respuesta para reflejar mi comentario anterior y completar tu respuesta

Comment: @Hersenfels haciendo esa observación, ya modifiqué mi respuesta para darte una aproximación a cómo podría hacerse.

Comment: @Pikoh ¡muchas gracias por tu comentario! Ya lo añadí ;)

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider Amigo, soy nuevo en este sitio, ya arregle mi función, pero no se como replicar mi respuesta y como marcar que me fuiste de ayuda. de ante mano gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, saludos.

Comment: @Hersenfels solo da clic a la palomita que aparece del lado izquierdo de mi respuesta (debajo del "1" grande que está ahí), con eso indicas que la respuesta fue de ayuda :) ¡un saludo!